# Showing similar games in play store

Tags: android, google-play

A day ago I uploaded my first game in play store and I'm having an issue and I don't know if it is normal.

My entry in play store is not showing similar games like the others. I don't know if it is because it has been too few time in the market or I have to activate it :/. I assigned the type of the game and so on... is there any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you dont have to activate it separately. In due course of time it will start to show it. It is based on people's behavior of downloading your app and similar apps like yours..